# How to load images in a for loop in django template?

Tags: html, django, image, for-loop, django-templates

For a name generator I want to show the alphabet (like clickable images) to filter the initial but I have problem to load the images in the for loop.

Here two tentatives in my `.html`:

```
  {% for letter in initials %}
    <a href="#" onclick="FilterByInitial()"><img width='32' height='32' src="{% static 'lists/icons/{{ letter }}_grey.ico' %}" alt='{{ letter }}' /></a>

    {% with letter|add:'_grey.ico' as myimage %}
      <a href="#" onclick="FilterByInitial()"><img width='32' height='32' src="{% static 'lists/icons/myimage' %}" alt='{{ letter }}' /></a>
    {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Where initials is a string with all the letters:

```
initials = ascii_lowercase
```

the network tab in my firefox gives `myimage` and `{{ letter }}_grey.ico` not found. The page shows the replacement text. And this works:

```
src="{% static 'lists/icons/a_grey.ico' %}"
```

I even try to add `|safe` but a no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approaches do not work because template variables within strings are not evaluated.

Try this:

```
{% with 'lists/icons/'|add:letter|add:'_grey.ico' as myimage %}
  <a href="#" onclick="FilterByInitial()">
    <img width='32' height='32' src="{% static myimage %}" alt='{{ letter }}' />
  </a>
{% endwith %}
```

Alternatively, you can create a custom filter, like this:

```
# templatetags/image_tags.py
@register.filter
def image_for_letter(letter):
    return f'lists/icons/{letter}_grey.ico'


{% load image_tags %}
...
  <a href="#" onclick="FilterByInitial()">
    <img width='32' height='32' src="{% static letter|image_for_letter %}" alt='{{ letter }}' />
  </a>
{% endwith %}
```